# Belongs_to build syntax using .to_sym

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a line of code that works great for building objects that have has_many associations:

```
object_form_builder.object.send(type.to_sym).build
```

As you can likely appreciate, this does not work for belongs_to relationships, where the syntax needs to be `build_obect` rather than `object.build`.

Is there a way to reformat this code so that it will work with a belongs_to relationship?

Comment: Isn't that just going to return a true or false? How will that build the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
object_form_builder.send("build_#{type}")
```